# Simple concatenated json line breaker in Splunk

Tags: line-breaks, splunk

I know this is probably simple, but for some reason I am able to get a line breaker working in Splunk.  I am fetching a data source from AWS S3, and multiple events in JSON format are concatenated. e.g.

```
{"key":"value", {"composite":"result"}}{"something":"else"}
```

So LINE_BREAKER should match on `}{` with the left brace included.

I have `SHOULD_LINEMERGE=false` and then `LINE_BREAKER=(\{.+\})\{` but i loose the closing bracket. The `}{` don't have any characters between them (not even a newline), what is the best way to split these?

Comment: I've also noticed that the linkbreaking processor is truncating the entry: ` LineBreakingProcessor - Truncating line because limit of 100000 bytes has been exceeded with a line length >= 106496 - data_source="s3://...."`

Comment: The event always starts consistently, e.g. with `{"key"` so I am trying with BREAK_ONLY_BEFORE=\{\"key\" 

and have added a TRUNCATE=512000

Comment: TRUNCATE=0 and BREAK_ONLY_BEFORE = \{\"key\" is not working

Comment: Have you properly tagged this sourcetype with `KV_MODE=JSON` in your props.conf? Splunk *should* handle JSON without extra effort on your part (unless the JSON is truly broken)

Comment: Should this be deployed to the indexer cluster or on the heavy forwarder that fetches the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LINE_BREAKER` attribute requires a capture group, but discards the text that matches the capture group.  The solution is to be more creative with the regex.

```
LINE_BREAKER=\}()\{
```

Empty capture groups are allowed.

Your comments confuse matters.  Are events separated by `}{` or by `{"key"`?  The value of `LINE_BREAKER` should be set to whatever separates events.  Once you've established that then you can address the `TRUNCATE` setting.

Comment: Finally got around to testing this, works great. Thanks, didn't think of an empty capture group.